# Array inside an Object with specific key to access

Tags: php

So I have here an object of an `photo` inside that object there's a bunch of arrays with key's & values :

```
{
     "photos": [
                {
                  "logo": false,
                  "type": "MAIN",
                  "url": "/uploads/userpics/503892/FiyxpMqMQj.png",
                  "publicUrl": "https:test.com/medium_FiyxpMqMQj.png"
                },
                {
                  "logo": true,
                  "type": "LOGO",
                  "url": "/uploads/userpics/503892/kLwxKH6rIx.png",
                  "publicUrl": "https://test.com/medium_kLwxKH6rIx.png"
                },
                 {
                  "logo": false,
                  "type": "MAIN",
                  "url": "/uploads/userpics/543292/FiyxpMqMQj.png",
                  "publicUrl": "https:test.com/medium_asd432MQj.png"
                }
              ]
}
```

what I want is after i ran this object into `foreach` it will display or get the `"publicUrl"` of the key value `"logo"=true` or `"type"="LOGO"` is that possible ?

Comment: Have you looked into json_decode?  This will provide an array which should then be processed by foreach.

Comment: @Nigel yes I did json decode the `reponse`  and did the `foreach`  and I don't know how can I get just the array of data with the value of ` "logo"=true` or `"type":"LOGO"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming $photos is the original data and that you have shown the data at the beginning level then you could do something like:

```
$json=json_decode( $photos );
foreach( $json as $obj ){
    if( $obj->logo==true or $obj->type=='LOGO' ){
        echo $obj->publicUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you mate .. got it working and yes correct it not the original data I just need the logic .. this what I've done.
 $parsed_json = json_decode($response, true);
  $pj = $parsed_json["response"]["location"];
 $pt = $pj['photos'];
 foreach( $pt as $obj ){
    if( $obj['logo']==true or $obj['type']=='LOGO' ){
     $waha = $obj['publicUrl'];
         $output .= '<input type="text" value="'.$waha.'" name="ubphotos">';
     }
 }

Answer (score 1):

First, this is not a valid JSON. But once you fix it, [json_decode($array, true)](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) will convert your JSON to regular array (2nd parameter is important for that) and then you can use normal `foreach($array as $key=>$val) { echo "{$k} = {$v}" }` to iterate over it.  JSON arrays got no custom keys, so expect `0, 1 ....` sequence.